# Help with an Inverse Trigonometry Integral 2

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Evaluate

> $$\int^{1/{\sqrt{3}}}_{-1/{\sqrt{3}}} \frac{x^4}{1-x^4}\cos^{-1}\frac{2x}{1+x^2} \mathrm{d}x$$

---

The Solution: We try to eliminate $\cos^{-1}\frac{2x}{1+x^2}$ by using the relation $$\pi - cos^{-1}(a) = cos^{-1}(a)$$
Consider the first 3 steps:$$$$
$$I=\int^{1/{\sqrt{3}}}_{-1/{\sqrt{3}}} \frac{x^4}{1-x^4}\cos^{-1}\frac{2x}{1+x^2} \mathrm{d}x$$
Putting $x=-t$
$$I=\int^{1/{\sqrt{3}}}_{-1/{\sqrt{3}}} \frac{(-t)^4}{1-(-t)^4}\cos^{-1}\frac{2(-t)}{1+(-t)^2} (-dt)$$
$$I=\int^{1/{\sqrt{3}}}_{-1/{\sqrt{3}}} \frac{t^4}{1-t^4}(\pi -cos^{-1}\frac{2t}{1+t^2}) (-\mathrm{d}t) $$ $$$$
Now, how do we add both of these:

$$\int^{1/{\sqrt{3}}}_{-1/{\sqrt{3}}} \frac{x^4}{1-x^4}\cos^{-1}\frac{2x}{1+x^2} \mathrm{d}x +\int^{1/{\sqrt{3}}}_{-1/{\sqrt{3}}} \frac{t^4}{1-t^4}(\pi -cos^{-1}\frac{2t}{1+t^2}) (-\mathrm{d}t)$$ Could somebody please show this in detail?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $I$ be given by

$$I=\int_{-\sqrt{3}/3}^{\sqrt{3}/3}\frac{x^4}{1-x^4} \arccos\left(\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right)dx$$

Upon substituting $x\to -x$ we find that

$$\begin{align}
I&=\int_{-\sqrt{3}/3}^{\sqrt{3}/3}\frac{x^4}{1-x^4} \arccos\left(\frac{-2x}{1+x^2}\right)dx\\\\
&=\int_{-\sqrt{3}/3}^{\sqrt{3}/3}\frac{x^4}{1-x^4} \left(\pi-\arccos\left(\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right)\right)dx\\\\
&=\pi\,\int_{-\sqrt{3}/3}^{\sqrt{3}/3}\frac{x^4}{1-x^4}dx-\int_{-\sqrt{3}/3}^{\sqrt{3}/3}\frac{x^4}{1-x^4} \arccos\left(\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right)dx\\\\
&=\pi\,\int_{-\sqrt{3}/3}^{\sqrt{3}/3}\frac{x^4}{1-x^4}dx-I
\end{align}$$

Thus,

> $$I=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{-\sqrt{3}/3}^{\sqrt{3}/3}\frac{x^4}{1-x^4} dx$$

---

The integral $I=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{-\sqrt{3}/3}^{\sqrt{3}/3}\frac{x^4}{1-x^4} dx$ can be evaluated in closed form.  First we note that

$$\frac{x^4}{1-x^4}=-1+\frac{1}{1-x^4}$$

Thus, $I$ becomes

$$I=-\pi\sqrt{3}/3+\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{-\sqrt{3}/3}^{\sqrt{3}/3}\frac{1}{1-x^4} dx$$

Next, we use partial fraction expansion to write

$$\frac{1}{1-x^4}=\frac{1/4}{1-x}+\frac{1/4}{1+x}+\frac{1/2}{1+x^2}$$

whereby we find that

$$\begin{align}
I&=-\pi\sqrt{3}/3+\frac{\pi}{8} \int_{-\sqrt{3}/3}^{\sqrt{3}/3}\frac{1}{1-x}dx+\frac{\pi}{8} \int_{-\sqrt{3}/3}^{\sqrt{3}/3}\frac{1}{1+x}dx+\frac{\pi}{4} \int_{-\sqrt{3}/3}^{\sqrt{3}/3}\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx\\\\
&=-\pi\sqrt{3}/3+\frac{\pi}{4}\log\left(2+\sqrt{3}\right)+\pi^2/12\\\\
&=\frac{\pi}{4}\log(2+\sqrt{3})+\frac{\pi^2}{12}-\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{3}}
\end{align}$$

Finally, $abcdef+1=577$.

Comment: @BetterWorld When substituting $x \to -x$, we have $dx \to -dx$ AND the limits of integration transform from $(-\sqrt{3}/3,\sqrt{3}/3)$ to $(\sqrt{3}/3,-\sqrt{3}/3)$.  So, one can absorb the minus sign of the differential by flipping the integration limits.

Comment: On the second question, the second integral is not quite correct.  The limits of integration need to be flipped of the term $-dt$ needs to be changed to $dt$ as explained in the previous note..

Comment: Why do you want to add these?  The first integral $I$ is equal to the second one.   And the second one is equal to $\pi \int \frac{t^4}{1-t^4}dt-I$.  Thus, $2I=\pi \int \frac{t^4}{1-t^4}dt$ and so $I=\pi \frac12 \int \frac{t^4}{1-t^4}dt$.

Comment: I understand.   So, $\int_a^b f(x)dx+\int_a^b g(t)dt=\int_a^b (f(x)+g(x))dx=\int_a^b (f(t)+g(t))dt$.  In the example in one of your comments, the sum is just $\pi \int \frac{t^4}{1-t^4}dt$.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  I just want to give you the best answer I can.